# js - question mark after a variable name

Tags: javascript

I can't find any reference to the following syntax:

```
data?.length > 0 && ...rest of the code
```

I understand the double ampersand and the rest. The only thing I'm not clear about is the question mark rigth after the 'data' variable. What does it mean or what's it's called? I can't find anyting on that.

Normally, I'd check if a variable exists (is true) with the following:

```
data && if_data_is_true_execute_this
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: The "safety" operator, my team affectionately calls it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a new ECMAScript 2020 feature which allows you to check if a property exists before you try to access it  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining